# Solr Stats per Group

Tags: solr

I've been experimenting with Solr (5.2.1) groups and stats and I am getting nowhere. I have a bunch of documents grouped by a key. I am returning the groups in my results and I want to return the minimum value of a field for each group. Note that I ONLY need it for the groups being returned in the search query.

I am able to get the stats component working, however it just returns the results for all groups; like regular facets.

Here is the query:

```
facet=true&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=t1}pr&facet.pivot={!stats=t1}groupid
```

I also tried to use stats.facet component without any luck. Am I missing something here or is this not in Solr?

Answer (score 5):

For example, you have following fields

id, name, category, score

11,name1,A,1

22,name2,A,2

33,name3,B,1

44,name4,B,2

55,name5,B,3
Then you can group based on category, and inside group, you can get stats based on field score.

```
q=*%3A*&fl=count&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=t1}score&facet.pivot={!stats=t1}category
```

Results would be like

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{},
    "facet_dates":{},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{},
    "facet_pivot":{
      "sentiment_cat":[{
          "field":"sentiment_cat",
          "value":"SECOND",
          "count":3,
          "stats":{
            "stats_fields":{
              "sentiment_score":{
                "min":1.0,
                "max":3.0,
                "count":3,
                "missing":0,
                "sum":6.0,
                "sumOfSquares":14.0,
                "mean":2.0,
                "stddev":1.0}}}},
        {
          "field":"sentiment_cat",
          "value":"FIRST",
          "count":2,
          "stats":{
            "stats_fields":{
              "sentiment_score":{
                "min":1.0,
                "max":2.0,
                "count":2,
                "missing":0,
                "sum":3.0,
                "sumOfSquares":5.0,
                "mean":1.5,
                "stddev":0.7071067811865476}}}}]}}
```

As you can see, min, max, sum are done on score field. This is the capability of facet and stat. let me know, if you need something different from above

Comment: Thanks Ramzy, the entire problem with this is that the results of the facet pivot are based of general facets and not the returned groups. I need the stats for the groups returned in the search query.

Comment: "need stats for groups returned in search query" - can you please laborate, may be with help of above example

Comment: This returns facets like they are always returned in Solr; by count. It doesn't mean that the groups that are returned in the search request are included in the facet pivot. You will need more data to replicate this.

Comment: Sorry did not get you. Anyways, if you need more help, we can discuss with example of your choice, or else Happy Learning

Comment: Lets say you have 20 million items. When you run a search query you will get back lets say 10 groups that are most relevant to your search query. However, these 10 groups are not guaranteed to be included in the facets. The facets will be returned based on the highest count of items in groups, which may not be the ones returned in the search request. Search request returned by relevance.... facets returned by count of items.... make sense?

Comment: Just confirming, is it that the faceting works on search results. I mean first you get the search results, and then if there is faceting, you group on the results. Help me if I am missing something